# number of unread messages from xmpp ios

Tags: objective-c, message, xmppframework, ios8.1

I am developing a chat App using `XMPPFrameWork`. Everything is working
 perfectly but I'm stuck at obtaining number of unread messages. I've to show on
 `tableView` the number of messages that are not opened yet. How should I proceed
 , any idea? I tried to show the `mostRecentMessage` but it didn't work.
 Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is an attribute  named "unreadMessages" in  "XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject" in XMPP. Pass the FROM "jid" to get the corresponding user object and Increment "unreadMessages" value in below method in Appdelegate,

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

and update it in the same db again.Like,

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [self.xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[message fromStr] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]objectAtIndex:0] ]]
                                                                          xmppStream:self.xmppStream
                                                                managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    NSNumber *number = user.unreadMessages;

    int value = [number intValue];

    number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value + 1];

    user.unreadMessages = number;
```

Then use the above code in any viewcontroller to retrieve unread message count.

Comment: i have use your code..but it return user every time nil.

Comment: it works for me..if the USER is nil,obviously the JID you passed is wrong or not in proper format..please check it.

Comment: @VijayKarthik  i had written above code but even if user read the message its shows in unread message count.... and when need to set it to 0.. how we know messages is read or not...